# Mostrar la edad a partir de una fecha registrada en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

le escribo en esta oportunidad ya que tengo el siguiente código la cual tengo que mostrar la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento registrado en una base de datos, tengo un código para hacer el cálculo de la edad pero me da un error (error: Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento_vecino in C:xXXXX/eye.php on line 92) además de que no consigo como agregarlo para que me haga el ECHO dentro de la tabla considerando que el ECHO para que se muestre el resultado de cálculo de edad es `<?php echo $interval->format('%y años'); ?>`

Gracias por toda su ayuda.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
              <tr>
                <th class="center">#</th> 
                <th class="center">Cédula</th>
                <th class="center">Nombres</th>
                <th class="center">Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                <th class="center">Edad</th>
              </tr>
            
            <tbody>
            <?php  
            $no = 1;
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT cedula_vecino, nombres_vecino, nacimiento_vecino FROM comunidad_vecino WHERE cedula_inmueble='$_GET[id]' ORDER BY cedula_vecino ASC");

            //Calcula la fecha de Nacimiento
            $data = new DateTime($data['nacimiento_vecino']); 
// error: Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento_vecino in C:xXXXX/eye.php on line 92
            $today = new DateTime('now');
            $interval = $today->diff($data);


            if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
              while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

              echo "<tr>
                      <td width='10' class='center'>$no</td>
                      <td width='10' align='center'>$data[cedula_vecino]</td>
                      <td width='60' class='left'>$data[nombres_vecino]</td>
                      <td width='10' align='center'>$data[nacimiento_vecino]</td>
                      <td width='10' align='center'>$interval->$format[%y años]</td>
                    </tr>";
            $no++;
            }
          }else{

             echo "</tbody></table>
              <div align='center'>No existen datos</div>";   
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: ¿No debería ser `$query['nacimiento_vecino']`?

Comment: No deberías calcular la diferencia dentro del while. Y para mostrarlo dentro del echo concatenar con el .  "<td width='10' align='center'>$interval->".$format[%y años]."</td>""

Comment: Ahora sele el error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%', expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabajos\sirgoco\modules\vivienda\eye.php on line 106

Comment: Estas intentando usar `$data` antes del fetch.

Comment: No le pongas solucionado al título, con marcar una respuesta como aceptada alcanza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a asumir que los datos están bien guardados, en una columna del tipo DATETIME. Como en el caso de Postgres, en MySQL dispones de una función que nos ayudará a hacer esto directamente, llamada TIMESTAMPDIFF(). Esta función recibe como argumentos la unidad de tiempo en la que queremos recibir la respuesta y las dos fechas entre las que queremos obtener la diferencia. Veamos el ejemplo para obtener la edad de alguien con esta función, sirviéndonos de una tabla de ejemplo llamada clientes que contendrá una columna FechaNac con la fecha de nacimiento de los mismos:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,FechaNac,CURDATE()) AS edad
     FROM clientes;
```